# How to migrate google site to SharePoint Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, google-analytics

Have to migrate google site to SharePoint site is there any free tools available to do it?

How to migrate It?

Comment: What's a "google site"?

Comment: google site is like google's website service, it's quiet familiar and free of cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate your google site to SharePoint site using following tools:

1. [Metalogix Tool to migrate google site to SharePoint](http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/Google%20Edition/000_Introduction/Index.htm)
2. [CLOUDIWAY Collaborative Sites Migration](http://www.cloudiway.com/products/cloudiway-site-migration/)
3. [BitTitan Community](https://community.bittitan.com/kb/Pages/Google%20Sites%20Migration%20Guide2.aspx)

There are many more tools available on market, some needs license and some provide you trials as well. So depending on your needs you can go with any one of them.